# Cannot create COM object from ASP.NET (Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed... error: 8007000e)

Tags: asp.net, com

I have an API DLL which is a COM object. I’ve used this DLL in a Winforms application successfully.  When I use it in ASP.NET application I get the `E_OUTOFMEMORY error: “Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8007000e”` when I create an instance of the COM object.

Although I don’t think it is a security issue, I’ve tried using windows authentication and also to give privileges to the ASPNET user with no use.

I don’t have the source code of the COM object.
I'm using .NET Framework 3.5.

Thanks in advance,
Sharon.

Comment: Does it work if the ASP.NET app is running under an Application Pool with the same user id as the winforms app? Also what does it say in the windows event viewer

Comment: Actually the problem occurs in the development environment with the ASP.NET development server. I didn't published it to the IIS yet. The development server run with the same credentials as the winforms application (my own), although I'm not sure what are the credentials of the web site withing the development server. There is nothing in the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio / Tools / Error Lookup reveals:

```
"Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."
```

This isn't necessarily an OOM exception, I've had cases in serialization where deserializing the object size silently failed returning -1, and the subsequent allocation failed with an OOM exception (because usually (unsigned)-1 == all memory except one element).

Comment: I thing that the actual message depends on the source of the error. Anyway. .NET wraps it with system.outofmemoryexception. this can be the scenario in this case, but i don't have the source code of the COM object so I can't check it. I'm trying to contact the developer of the API, but I'm not sure he can help.

Comment: *"depends on the source"* - that's should be the case only if the Facility is FACILITY_ITF (0x8004xxxx). This one's a ` HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`, which should be independent of the interface.

Comment: OK, I accept the correction. But it still has similar meaning (or am I missing something here?). The main difference between the two applications is that the first one is winforms and the second is ASP.NET. If I knew what the COM object is doing in its instantiation, I could tell if the reported error is the result of previous error. How can I continue the investigation without having the source code?

Comment: generally: Try to reproduce in a minimal environment, if it still occurs, ask thedevelopers. If it doesn't, check the differences between the two environments, and eliminate them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of investigation we found that the problem is in the API.

Thanks for everyone.

Sharon.